# vue-recaptcha / Laravel Mix: Enviar Recaptcha a través de Axios al backend

Tags: vue.js, axios

Tengo un pequeño formulario construido en vue y estoy utilizando `vue-recaptcha` para mostrar el captcha desde el componente.

**Actualmente esto es lo que tengo o algo similar:**

```html
<template>
  <form @submit="register">
      <input type="text" name="anyname">
      <vue-recaptcha sitekey="Your key here" :loadRecaptchaScript="true"></vue-recaptcha>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';
  export default {
    ...
    components: {
      VueRecaptcha
    },
    methods: {
      register() {
        axios
          .post("/contact", {
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            phone: this.phone,
            body: this.body,
          })
          .then(response =>
            this.responseMessage(
              response.data.code,
              response.data.response
            )
          )
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }

    }
  };
</script>
```

Lo cierto es que tengo mi `axios.post`, actualmente me envia todos loa parametros bien al backend pero no encuentro como vincular el `<vue-recaptcha>` probé con un `v-model` pero obviamente no funciona.

Si alguien ha trabajado ya con esta libreria `vue-recaptcha` y sepa como enviar el captcha al backend a través de `axios` para poder validarlo le agradezco la información.

Comment: ¿Ya checaste esto: https://www.itechempires.com/2018/05/how-to-implement-google-recapcha-with-vuejs-and-laravel-5-6/?

Comment: Saludos Beta, gracias por tu respuesta. Estoy investigando a ver si el componente `<vue-recaptcha>`me brinda la manera de poder acceder al value del campo, pero hasta ahora no he conseguido nada. Lo que pensé que iba a ser un formulario sencillo que todo quedaría en un .vue, ahora veo que tendré que tocar código de laravel, además del que tenía dispuesto para el controlador.